# Simplify two Get web-services very similar

Tags: .net, web-services, get, svc

I'm building some web services in Svc (not WebApi) and I need to write two different methods (+ interfaces) to do similar things:

1. List orders by company used in a filtered menu:

   */orders/list?companycode={companyCode}*
2. List orders by company and suppliers where company and supplier are required (also for security reason..supplier is related to the user is filtering):

   */orders/listbysup?companycode={companyCode}&suppliercode={suppliercode}*

Is it possible to write only one web service using something like optional/required parameters?

Now I'm using two different methods: list vs listbysup.

Maybe I can use also another parameter as filtering "mode".

I can also use something like

```
var mode = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters["mode"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is totally possible and it would depend on what you return. If the result is exactly the same but method 2 you are passing in the supplier code as a `filter` then there would be no difference. A quick check if query string `list?companycode={companyCode}` does not contain `&suppliercode` it tells the method to return the list just for the company code with no filtering.

However, if the results are different then you would break the `S  -> Single Responsibility` in the `SOLID` principals. A method should have one purpose and one purpose only. You can write code to return different results in one method but that would be non-ideal creating unnecessary tech debt. It might also proof to be difficult to create tests for complicated methods. Having more than one method with a single purpose makes it clean and easy to maintain.

Comment: Ok, it's clear. But while the first method is only a filtering where I can add other filters in the future, the second one is used to fill a dropdownlist and need companycode and suppliercode also for security reason. How can I use only one mehod? Thanks

Comment: You can always add more on demand `list?companycode={companyCode}&suppliercode={suppliercode}&productCode={productcode}...` then check if these exist in the query string. If not then ignore.

Comment: Ehm no. If I use the same method… in the first case the parameter must be optional, in the second it's required. Now I have two different method: list vs listbysup